# Create my own disk server

Tags: linux, file-sharing, disk

I have been wondering how all these small nas boxes that run linux can share over network and usb. The network part is totally under control, but I am completely at a loss on how I could hook up a computer to my server through USB cable, and get a share.

Is this done with some specific hardware or is this done through software ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the NAS' that I've encountered make use of Samba and then share these USB mounted disks out as Samba shares.

Rules like this can be put in your `/etc/fstab` file:

```
$ blkid
/dev/sda2: LABEL="OS" UUID="DAD9-00EF" TYPE="vfat"
```

This line can be adapted to this:

```
/dev/sda2    /export/somedir ntfs    defaults            1 2
```

Once this USB drive is mounted at boot up, Samba can be used to share out `/export/somedir`.

```
# /etc/samba/smb.conf
[xbox_videos]
  comment = Videos for Xbox
  path = /export/somedir
  browseable = yes
; available = yes
  guest ok = no
; read only = yes
  public = yes
  inherit permissions = yes
  writeable = yes
  hosts allow = 192.168.0. 192.168.1. localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

Both hardware and software. https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/gadget.html Although there are USB "cables" with NIC built in that allow two USB hosts to talk to each other (via the USB network adapter). Which is slow as network-over-usb has way more overhead than regular USB.